# How to select values on mysql database for each value from checkbox array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a bulk action.
I have checkboxes,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_id[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_id[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_id[]" value="3">
```

I wanted to select values from mysql table for each selected checkboxes then use my function to delete data based on the fetched values. I tried,

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count( $_POST['check_id'] ); $i++ ) {
  $manufacturers_id = prepare_input($_POST['check_id'][$i]);
  $manufacturer_query = mysql_query("select manufacturers_image from " . TABLE_MANUFACTURERS . " where manufacturers_id = '" . (int)$manufacturers_id . "'");
  $manufacturer = mysql_fetch_array($manufacturer_query);

  delete_image(DIR_IMAGES . $manufacturer['manufacturers_image']);
}
```

The problem is that, there is no fetched mysql values based on `$_POST['check_id']` even though im sure that i have `manufacturers_image` where is `manufacturers_id` is either 1,2 or 3.

Is there a correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: try foreach($_POST['check_id'] as $i=>$value)

Comment: What does prepare_input function do? try echo $_POST['check_id'][$i] before that function to check if you're receiving values

Comment: @Hamurabi there is receiving values.. like array([0] => 1).. its just mysql_escape_string..

Comment: @fluty I tried foreach but its not working either.

Comment: @Ken then do the following, echo the query to check if it is the right query. ex: echo "select manufacturers_image from " . TABLE_MANUFACTURERS . " where manufacturers_id = '" . (int)$manufacturers_id ."'";

Comment: @Hamurabi it displayed the right query.. `select manufacturers_image from wp_16_manufacturers where manufacturers_id = '1'`. I tried to use this query using phpmyadmin and it returned the right value.. Then why its not fetching using php?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
$manufacturer = mysql_fetch_array($manufacturer_query);
```

to

```
$manufacturer = mysql_fetch_assoc($manufacturer_query);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is returning an array ... you use `while()` or you fetch first image

```
delete_image(DIR_IMAGES . $manufacturer[0]['manufacturers_image']);
```